# How can I use flutter's "--obfuscate" flag with fastlane on iOS

Tags: ios, flutter, fastlane, fastlane-gym

I have a fastlane lane that builds the app using `gym` or `build_app` but I also want to use `flutter build`'s `--obfuscate` flag.

```rb
  desc "Build - Enterprise"
  lane :build_enterprise do |options|
    bundle_id = options[:bundle_id]

    sync_certificates_and_provisioning_profiles(
      type: "enterprise",
      bundle_id: bundle_id,
    )
    cleanup
    gym(
      scheme: get_scheme(bundle_id),
      export_method: "enterprise",
      clean: true,
      include_bitcode: false,
      include_symbols: true,
      export_options: {
        signingStyle: "manual",
        provisioningProfiles: generate_enterprise_profiles(bundle_id)
      }
    )
  end
```

As I understand, I can replace `gym` with `flutter build ios --obfuscate` but then how can I make use of other parameters that `gym` provides. Such as: `export_method`, `export_options`, `include_bitcode`, `include_symbols`? I have multiple flavors in the app and using these parameters based on debug/release app or staging/production app is quite useful.

Comment: Hi @Rohan, have you found a solution for this?

Comment: No I haven't :/

Comment: So, I presume you build the app by `flutter build ipa` and specifying the options you need?

Comment: No I use gym itself. No obfuscation.

Answer (score 1):

You can't add this via fastlane-gym. In the project_directory>iOS>Flutter>Generated.xcconfig file add

```
DART_OBFUSCATION=true
```